# How to resize Windows partition when dual booting?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have Linux has as my main OS and Windows being Dual-booted for my printer and just in case. This is my how my partitions are done so far:

[Screenshot of GParted with partition layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWlKw.png)

So basically I have a EFI partition, the root partition, a home partition and my Windows partition. I had given only 32GB to Windows but with all the drivers and stuff installed its not enough.

**How could I shrink my home partition and give more room to Windows (mostly +8GB)?**

I asked this because as to do this I would have to shrink my home partition and then move the start of my Windows partition and I thought that would mess up the Windows boot manager looking of where the Windows Partition starts.

Comment: BIOS/MBR or UEFI/gpt? Usually UEFI uses gpt and Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. And requires MBR partitioning for BIOS boot. Drive is not generous for dual booting. Any Windows partition change should be done from Windows with immediate reboot to run chkdsk as that is normally required after a resize.

Comment: Its UEFI/gpt. So do you suggest that I shrink the home partition with GParted (as that can't be done in Windows). Then go to Windows disk manager and just increase the size of Local Disk C:?

Comment: Windows in UEFI boot mode typically wants a lot of additional partitions. it will share an ESP - efi system partition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: And, lastly, make sure the unallocated space you want to resize with is contiguous to the partition being expanded. Depending on the relative position of your partition you may need to move one or more, with increasing risk of data loss. Backups are a must.